# EF lambda: How to fetch all data that match any id from a List

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have all selected `Product.Id` (guids) inside a `List<Guid> cartList`. I'm trying to get all matched products with a lambda expression through Entity Framework.

```
List<Product> getProducts = db.Products.Where(x=> x.Id == /*that contains any ids in cartList*/)
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: `cartList.Contains(x.Id)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<Product> getProducts = db.Products.Where(x=> cartList.Contains(x.Id)).ToList()
```

Comment: Probably no need to explicitly .ToList() it. Leave it as an Iqueryable and it will iterate only when it needs to.